# Inno Setup save user inputs from an after-installation custom page to registry?

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

Related to this question:
[In Inno Setup how to save user inputs to registry?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42989109/in-inno-setup-how-to-save-user-inputs-to-registry/49300028#49300028)

When doing this:

```pascal
[Code]

var
  UserInputsPage: TInputQueryWizardPage;

function GetUserName(Param: string): string;
begin
  Result := UserInputsPage.Values[0];
end;

function GetUserBirthday(Param: string): string;
begin
  Result := UserInputsPage.Values[1];
end;

procedure InitializeWizard;
begin
  { Create the page }
  UserInputsPage :=
    CreateInputQueryPage(wpWelcome,
      'User information', 'User name and birthday',
      'Please specify the following information, then click Next.');
  UserInputsPage.Add('Name:', False);
  UserInputsPage.Add('Birthday:', False);
end;

[Registry]
Root: HKCU; Subkey: "Software\My Company\My Program"; \
    ValueType: string; ValueName: "UserName"; ValueData: "{code:GetUserName}"
Root: HKCU; Subkey: "Software\My Company\My Program"; \
    ValueType: string; ValueName: "UserBirthday"; ValueData: "{code:GetUserBirthday}"
```

the user input is written to registry.

When I change

```pascal
CreateInputQueryPage(wpWelcome,
```

to

```pascal
CreateInputQueryPage(wpInstalling,
```

so I have:

```pascal
var
  UserInputsPage: TInputQueryWizardPage;

function GetUserName(Param: string): string;
begin
  Result := UserInputsPage.Values[0];
end;

function GetUserBirthday(Param: string): string;
begin
  Result := UserInputsPage.Values[1];
end;

procedure InitializeWizard;
begin
  { Create the page }
  UserInputsPage :=
    CreateInputQueryPage(wpInstalling,
      'User information', 'User name and birthday',
      'Please specify the following information, then click Next.');
  UserInputsPage.Add('Name:', False);
  UserInputsPage.Add('Birthday:', False);
end;

[Registry]
Root: HKCU; Subkey: "Software\My Company\My Program"; \
    ValueType: string; ValueName: "UserName"; ValueData: "{code:GetUserName}"
Root: HKCU; Subkey: "Software\My Company\My Program"; \
    ValueType: string; ValueName: "UserBirthday"; ValueData: "{code:GetUserBirthday}"
```

user input is not written to registry.

Could someone please tell why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the answer is obvious, a custom page with `AfterID = wpInstalling` is shown **after installation**.

So the registry keys are created before user has a chance to enter their value.

All information that is needed for installation has to be provided **before installation**.

Move your custom page earlier.

---

Or if you need to keep the page, where it is, you need to write the keys programaticaly using [`RegWriteStringValue` function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_regwritestringvalue).

For an example, see [How to write install path to registry after install is complete with Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13537841/850848).

Comment: I moved the page to appear after the license page (wpLicense). Thanks.